Mysterious man who becomes friend of a family but then tries to hurt them
I watched this movie maybe 10 years ago, if I remember well there were no famous actors. I think it is between 1990-2009, I can't say it for sure, was in Color and probably original language was English. 
It looked like a thriller for TV only, not a movie for the cinema.
What I remember is that the main character was a stranger who was so kind with a family composed by parents plus 2 children. 
This family lived in a mountain house. 
Overtime he gains their trust, as he looks like a very respectable person. But suddendly  he reveals to have evil intentions, as he causes a car accident to the children's grandparents for which they die, he imprisons the mother and the children...  
If I remember well he has a crush on the Father! At the end luckily someone is able to neutralize him.

Are you sure it's an English movie? Because it looks a lot like the French film Harry, un ami qui vous veut du bien (With a friend like Harry).
Imdb synopsis (start): 

Michel, his wife Claire and their three little daughters Jeanne, Sarah
  and Iris are traveling to their cottage in Switzerland to spend summer
  vacation. When they stop the car, Michel goes to the toilet and a man
  stares at him. Soon the man introduces himself as Harold "Harry"
  Balestoro, who studied with Michel in high school and knows him very
  well. When Michel and his family go to their car, Harry parks his
  Mercedes Benz and introduces his fiancée Plum to the couple and
  invites themselves to travel to Michel's house for a drink. Later her
  recalls by heart a poem written by Michel and shows that he was
  obsessed for Michel...

I think I remember the grand parents murder, and the synopsis talk about grandparents, without spoiling it.
Edit : I looked at the trailer on imdb, and you can see the Grandparent "accident" at 0:37

Great! Did you know that movie? Thank you so much!

yeah, I was the cinema operator for it like 17 years ago (I can't be so old...)...It's probably the only reason i watch it. it was not a big movie, that can explain your 'television' impression.
